# How to make Jacobian automatically in Mathematica

Tags: vector-calculus

If we have two vectors, $a$ and $b$, how can I make Jacobian matrix automatically in Mathematica?

$$ a=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1^3+2x_2^2 \\
 3x_1^4+7x_2
\end{array}
\right);b=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1 \\
 x_2
\end{array}
\right);J=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\partial \left(x_1^3+2x_2^2\right)}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial \left(x_1^3+2x_2^2\right)}{\partial x_2} \\
 \frac{\partial \left(3x_1^4+7x_2\right)}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial \left(3x_1^4+7x_2\right)}{\partial x_2}
\end{array}
\right);  $$

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The easiest way to get the Jacobian is

```
D[a,{b}]
```

To get the format of a matrix, you would do `MatrixForm[D[f, {x}]`, or `D[f, {x}]//MatrixForm`, as the comment by azdahak says.

There is no special matrix type in MMA - it's internally always stored as a list of lists.

**Edit**

Since this question is partly about the *format* of the matrix and its elements, I thought it's worth adding a definition that makes calculus output look prettier, and in the case of the Jacobian lets you write symbolic matrices like this:

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \frac{\partial f_{\text{x}}}{\partial x} &
>    \frac{\partial f_{\text{x}}}{\partial y} \\
>  \frac{\partial f_{\text{y}}}{\partial x} &
>    \frac{\partial f_{\text{y}}}{\partial y} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The definition was initially posted [as a comment on the Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/comment-page-1/):

```
Derivative /: 
 MakeBoxes[Derivative[α__][f1_][vars__Symbol], 
  TraditionalForm] := 
 Module[{bb, dd, sp}, 
  MakeBoxes[dd, _] ^= 
   If[Length[{α}] == 1, "\[DifferentialD]", "\[PartialD]"];
  MakeBoxes[sp, _] ^= "\[ThinSpace]";
  bb /: MakeBoxes[bb[x__], _] := RowBox[Map[ToBoxes[#] &, {x}]];
  FractionBox[ToBoxes[bb[dd^Plus[α], f1]], 
   ToBoxes[Apply[bb, 
     Riffle[Map[bb[dd, #] &, 
       Select[({vars}^{α}), (# =!= 1 &)]], sp]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
```

With this, you can get the above matrix form with traditional partial derivatives like this:

First define the vector components with subscripts as is conventional. To avoid confusion between subscripts and variable names, use strings for the subscripts:

```
fVector = Array[Subscript[f, {"x", "y"}[[#]]][x, y] &, 2]
```

Then form the Jacobian and display it in `TraditionalForm`:

```
D[fVector, {{x, y}}] // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

The result is as shown above.

**Edit**

In this answer to [How to make traditional output for derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/245) I posted a newer version of the derivative formatting that contains an `InterpretationFunction` which allows you to evaluate the derivatives despite their condensed displayed form.

Comment: but output is vector not Matrix?

Comment: How to print matrix J, to see output from Jarga?

Comment: Like this: D[{x^3+2y^2,3x^4+7y},{{x,y}}]//MatrixForm

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: this makes me so. happy. +1

Answer (score 25):

See: [Jacobian matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html)

> The Jacobian matrix and determinant can be computed using the
>   Mathematica commands:

```
JacobianMatrix[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] :=
    Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal@@(Dimensions/@{f,x})

JacobianDeterminant[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] :=
    Det[JacobianMatrix[f, x]] /;
      Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})
```

Some additional info.

```
a = {x1^3 + 2 x2^2, 3 x1^4 + 7 x2}
b = {x1, x2}
JacobianMatrix[a, b] // MatrixForm
```

[image: output]

Or maybe what you want looks like this:

```
 JacobianMatrix[b, a] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: it is not working as JacobianMatrix[a_List?VectorQ, b_List] := 
 Outer[D, a, b] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {a, b})

Comment: How to print matrix J, to see output?

Comment: it is not working as   Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

a = ( {
    {x1^3 + 2 x2^2},
    {3 x1^4 + 7 x2}
   } );

b = ( {
    {x1},
    {x2}
   } );

JacobianMatrix[a, b] // MatrixForm

Comment: Your comment code, a = ( { {x1^3 + 2 x2^2}, {3 x1^4 + 7 x2} } ); b = ( { {x1}, {x2} } ); defines 2 matrixes.  Placing the terms in vectors they should look like this: a ={x1^3 + 2 x2^2,3 x1^4 + 7 x2}; b = {x1, x2};

Answer (score 22):

`Grad[a,b]` also produces the Jacobian.

```
a = {x1^3 + 2 x2^2, 3 x1^4 + 7 x2};
b = {x1, x2};
Grad[a, b] // MatrixForm
```

This has the added advantage of letting you compute the Jacobian in different coordinate systems.

[image]