# Notation for implicit derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, custom-notation

Consider the following line of code:

```
D[x == y^3 + x y, x, NonConstants -> y]
```

The output would be:

```
1 == y + x D[y, x, NonConstants -> {y}] + 3 y^2 D[y, x, NonConstants -> {y}]
```

This is a confusing and cumbersome notation for the more natural:

```
1 == y + x y' + 3y^2 y'
```

I am trying to use the Notation package to help me replace the messy, default, output with the more natural one.
I have not succeeded.

Of-course I have read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives) Q.
The answer, if relevant, seems inaccessible to me, unfortunately.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related or a duplicate: [How to make traditional output for derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives).    Otherwise you should improve your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @artes: I don't see how I can change the display/notation of an implicit derivative using the answers supplied. Can you?

Comment: `expr /. D[y, x, NonConstants -> {y}] :> y'[x]` yields `1 == y + x y'[x] + 3 y^2 y'[x]`.

Comment: @Artes, thanks for the reply. Is there a way to make such a change permanent? As it is, it seems I need to post-fix each expression with your addition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but I guess if you have more equations you can do it once e.g. `{ l1==r1, l2==r2,..., ln==rn} /. D[y, x, NonConstants -> {y}] :> y'[x]`.

Comment: you're not satisfied with the result of `D[x == y[x]^3 + x y[x], x] /. {y[x] :> y, y'[x] :> y'}`, which is *exactly* the form you wanted?

Comment: You have typo `xy` in the original implicit equation; it should be `x y`.

Comment: @Murray,Artes , It is the result I wanted. What I'm asking, is if there's a way to hijack D[..., NonConstants->y], in such a way as to make this change permanent? So I wouldn't have to apply it specifically to each (group of) expression. Rather, do it once per-session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above I believe you are merely looking for a way to automate Artes' replacement.  Using [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24PrePrint.html):

```
$PrePrint = # /. {D[y_, x_, NonConstants -> {y_}] :> y'[x]} &;
```

Now:

```
D[x == y^3 + x y, x, NonConstants -> y]
```

> ```
> 1 == y + x y'[x] + 3 y^2 y'[x]
> ```

You could also use [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Post.html) or [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html) or [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html) depending on your specific needs.
Using `MakeBoxes` is usually robust and does not tie up `$Post` or `$PrePrint`.

```
MakeBoxes[D[y_, x_, NonConstants -> {y_}], fmt_] := ToBoxes[y'[x], fmt]
```

Comment: @Wizard Thanks. Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dt.html):

```
Dt[x == y^3 + x y, x]
(* 1 == y + x Dt[y, x] + 3 y^2 Dt[y, x] *)
```

You can specify literal constants with `SetAttributes`:

```
ClearAll[a];
SetAttributes[a, Constant];
Dt[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == a^2 x y, x]
(* 2 (x^2 + y^2) (2 x + 2 y Dt[y, x]) == a^2 y + a^2 x Dt[y, x] *)
```

If `x` and `y` might become dependent variables, then omit the second argument and you get:

```
de = Dt[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == a^2 x y]
(* 2 (x^2 + y^2) (2 x Dt[x] + 2 y Dt[y]) == a^2 y Dt[x] + a^2 x Dt[y] *)
```

You can turn `y` into an explicit function of `x`:

```
de /. y -> y[x]
(* 2 (x^2 + y[x]^2) (2 x Dt[x] + 2 Dt[x] y[x] y'[x]) == a^2 Dt[x] y[x] + a^2 x Dt[x] y'[x] *)
```

If you want to turn `x` into the dependent variable, you can replace `Dt[x]` by `1`:

```
de /. y -> y[x] /. Dt[x] -> 1
(* 2 (x^2 + y[x]^2) (2 x + 2 y[x] y'[x]) == a^2 y[x] + a^2 x y'[x] *)
```