# How to work with differentials explicitly?

Tags: differential-equations

When working with differential equations with independent (e.g. `t` )and dependent (e.g., `x[t]`) variables Mathematica expresses partial and 'regular' derivatives nicely, but not the derivative itself. Can anybody manage to do this?

I give an example:
Let `f` depend on `x`, `y` and `t`. `x` and `y` depend on `t`. So, 
the partial derivative

[image]

with e.g. respect to `x` is in Matheamtica expressed by

> f^(1,0,0)[x,y,t]

, the derivative with respect to the independent variable

[image]

as an example by

```
x'[t]
```

. But how can I make Mathematica to show the derivative e.g.

[image]

explicitly?

Comment: Does `DifferentialD[x]` work for your purposes?

Comment: Using `Solve[Dt[w[l2[t], lp[t], t], t] == 0, Dt[lp[t], t]]`, I would then for instance like to see dlp. I tried to use your (adjusted) example instead of `Dt[lp[t], t]`. It did not work. What do you think?

Comment: Using the `Notation` package we can make `Dt` appear as `DifferentialD`, and both `Dt[w[x[t],y[t],t]]` and `Dt[w[x,y,t]]` seem to expand as I would expect. If you are after the functionality of exterior derivatives, you may need to define it. Maybe one of these packages can help. [1](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/482/), [2](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/683/), [3](http://www.digi-area.com/Mathematica/atlas/ref/d.php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dt.html) is one way to work with differentials, unless you're after the more advanced functionality Timothy Wofford linked to in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/how-to-work-with-differentials-explicitly#comment104560_33798).  I'm not sure whether you want to do calculus with differentials, for instance in differential equations, or just want them to be formatted in a certain way.

#### Formatting

For formatting derivatives and differentials, these may be of help:

- [How to make traditional output for derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives)
- [Notation for implicit derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33682/notation-for-implicit-derivative)

#### The derivative and Dt

The differential of a multivariable function:

```
w = f[x, y, t];
Dt[w]
(* Dt[t] * Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, t] + 
    Dt[y] * Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, t] + 
    Dt[x] * Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, t]   *)
```

The (matrix) derivative of `f` may be obtained with `D`

```
D[w, {{x, y, t}}]
(* {Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, t], 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, t], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, t]}
```

The output of `Dt[w]` above may also be obtained with

```
D[w, {{x, y, t}}] . Dt[{x, y, t}]
```

One can substitute functions for `x` and `y` to make them explicitly depending on `t`, and the Chain Rule is automatically applied (of course):

```
Dt[w] /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]} // Factor // InputForm
(* Dt[t]*
    (Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x[t], y[t], t] +
      y'[t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x[t], y[t], t] +
      x'[t]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], t])  *)
```

#### Differential equations and Dt

One can turn expressions in terms of `Dt[x]` etc. into differential equations:

```
dtToDE[diffForm_, vars_List, var_] /; MemberQ[vars, var] := 
  With[{indep = DeleteCases[vars, var]},
   0 == diffForm /. 
     Flatten[{Thread[Dt /@ indep -> D[Through[indep[var]], var]], 
       Thread[indep -> Through[indep[var]]]}] /. Dt[var] -> 1
   ];
dtToDE[diffForm_, vars_List, var_] := 
  D[Through[vars[var]], var] == 
   Extract[CoefficientList[diffForm, Dt /@ vars] /. 
     Thread[vars -> Through[vars[var]]], 
    1 + IdentityMatrix[Length[vars]]];

orthogonalTrajectory[diffForm_, vars_List] := 
  diffForm /. Thread[# -> Cross[#]] &[Dt /@ vars];
```

*Examples*

An exact differential.

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 x - y^2]                            (* the differential of f *)
ode = dtToDE[Dt[x^2 + y^2 x - y^2], {x, y}, x]   (* as a derivative equation *)
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]                             (* solution to the ODE *)
Solve[x^2 + y^2 x - y^2 == C[1]/2, y]            (* solution to f = constant *)

(* 2 x Dt[x] + y^2 Dt[x] - 2 y Dt[y] + 2 x y Dt[y] *)
(* 0 == 2 x + y[x]^2 - 2 y[x] Derivative[1][y][x] + 2 x y[x] Derivative[1][y][x] *)
(* {{y[x] -> -(Sqrt[-2 x^2 - C[1]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-1 + x]))},
    {y[x] ->   Sqrt[-2 x^2 - C[1]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-1 + x])}}  *)
(* {{y    -> -(Sqrt[-2 x^2 + C[1]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-1 + x]))},
    {y    ->   Sqrt[-2 x^2 + C[1]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-1 + x])}}  *)
```

A differential with an integrating factor (pasted from an old test's TeX file, converted to a differential form with `Dt`):

```
ode = dtToDE[x dy + y dx + 4 x^3 y^4 dy /. {dx -> Dt[x], dy -> Dt[y]}, {x, y}, x]
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
ode /. {y'[x] -> Hold[D[y[x], x]]} /. sol // ReleaseHold // Simplify
Times @@ Subtract @@@ DeleteDuplicates@Simplify[x y^2 == x y[x]^2 /. sol] == 0 // Simplify

(* 0 == y[x] + x y'[x] + 4 x^3 y[x]^4 y'[x]   -- ODE *)
(* {True, True, True, True}                   -- all branches of sol satisfy the ODE *)
(* x^2 (4 y^4 - 2 y^2 C[1]) == 1              -- the integral curve (hacked from sol) *)
```

A system of equations, following three orthogonal trajectories to the gradient of a function.

```
sols = NDSolveValue[
         {dtToDE[orthogonalTrajectory[Dt[(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 4 x y], {x, y}], {x, y}, t],
          x[0] == #, y[0] == #},
         {x, y}, {t, -1.35, 1.35}] & /@ {0.99, 1., 1.01};
ParametricPlot @@ {Through[#[t]] & /@ sols, Flatten @ {t, sols[[1,1]]["Domain"]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]