# How do I toggle between the program snippet form of a displayformula and the human readable form of the equation?

Tags: formatting

I have a DisplayFormulaNumbered cell in my Mathematica notebook.  If I use the Cell | Convert To menu item to convert the cell to Standard or Traditional Form, the formula is now rendered as a program snippet.  For example:

```
TextCell[RawBoxes[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"L","\[CenterDot]",RowBox[{RowBox[{"I","'"}],"'"}]}],RowBox[{"(","t",")"}]}],"+",RowBox[{RowBox[{"R","\[CenterDot]",RowBox[{"I","'"}]}],RowBox[{"(","t",")"}]}],"+",RowBox[{FractionBox["1","C"],"\[CenterDot]",RowBox[{"I","(","t",")"}]}]}],"=",RowBox[{RowBox[{"V","'"}],RowBox[{"(","t",")"}]}]}],TraditionalForm]],FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]]]
```

Is there a way to toggle this cell to the human readable form I started with?

Comment: Might it be that you used Show Expression by accident? You can undo that by using it again.

Comment: Not in this case.  The steps to reproduce are:

1.  Add a DisplayFormulaNumbered cell.
2.  Ctrl-F9 and enter formula
3.  Cell | Convert To TraditionalForm
4.  The equation is now converted to an expression.
5.  Cell | Show Expression shows an even longer expression.

The only solution I have found is delete the cell.  Re-enter the formula - and do not try any formatting or Cell Conversion.

Comment: I get the same but am wondering why you want to convert to `TraditionalForm` when you are using `DisplayFormula` style plus Ctrl-9 ...since this combination gives you traditional form equations.

Comment: I was experimenting - trying to get a publication quality form of the formula.  The equation is converted to an expression when using Cell Convert StandardForm or TraditionalForm.  I found that there was no way to get back to the human readable form after Cell Convert.

Comment: You can get publication quality formulas without using traditional form ...which apart from anything else render equations in bold by default.

Comment: You keep saying that you want publication quality equations. You **do not** need to convert to `TraditionalForm` for that. I'm repeating myself but you keep saying this. Have a look at this and many other Q&A here on typesetting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/any-way-to-make-my-equations-look-better-more-latex-like/36699#36699