# About making a fraction "taller"

Tags: formatting

I encountered 2 problema with displaying formula in text format.
[image]

- The variables in the formula is italic, I want to change them to normal.
- And the fraction size is too small, I want to make it to full size.

Should I edit the stylesheet? What exactly should I do?

Comment: Take a look at: [Any way to make my equations look better, more Latex like?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/any-way-to-make-my-equations-look-better-more-latex-like). There is a lot of information you may find useful. Or [preventing TraditionalForm from getting “squished”](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40796/5478)

Comment: Well, the closers beat me to an answer not contained in the linked "duplicates", which do not address the issue of italics (traditionally, variables are supposed to be in italics): Edit the stylesheet, choose the style Text, and set these options with the Format > OptionInspector: ` DefaultInlineFormatType->StandardForm,
 FractionBoxOptions->{AllowScriptLevelChange->False}`.  Next, you might want to set the font for `"InlineCell"` by entering the style name InlineCell and setting its font. (Assuming your text is in a Text cell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Row[{
"1.",
Invisible["space"],
 "(a)",
Invisible["space"],
"Find ",
HoldForm@TraditionalForm@Integrate["x"^2, x]
}]
```

which produces:

[image]

and this:

```
Row[{
"2.",
Invisible["space"],
"(a)",
Invisible["space"],
"Find ",
HoldForm@TraditionalForm@Integrate[Style[1/"x", 18], x]
}]
```

produces this:

[image]

- You can alter the size of the fraction within the [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Style.html?q=Style&lang=en) command.
- Quotation marks around characters "x" produces a [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/String.html?q=String&lang=en).
- Change the String within [`Invisible`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Invisible.html?q=Invisible&lang=en) to alter the spacing between surrounding items.