# Maintain written order in expression (lexicographic sorting rules)

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation, sorting

Is there any way I can get output to follow the *exact* order that I wrote it?

For instance (simple example)

```
x = z + a - b + c^2
```

comes out as

```
a - b + c^2 + z
```

Comment: see the examples in [HoldForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html), [Defer](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html)?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: There are similar questions already answered ([45067](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45067/10397) [127333](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127333/10397)). Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and therefore  [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). Please [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis in what was NOT answered in the other question. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy.