# Extract differential operator from differential form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators, format

Let's say I have :

```
a*u''[x]+b*u'[x]
```

where `a` and `b` are constant

I would need to get

> ```
> (a*d2/dx2 + b*d/dx)u[x]
> ```

Can anyone tell me how I could to proceed?

Comment: Do you mean you just want the output to be formatted in `TraditionalForm`? Then this could be a duplicate of [How to make traditional output for derivatives.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23659/245) But I guess you want the factorization with `u` appearing only once on the right. Is that the main issue? In that case, is it OK to always assume that `x` is the independent variable?

Comment: Hi Jens, Yes I want to factorize u[x] 
where x is independent variable and u[x] represent u is a function of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the desired form is not valid *Mathematica* code (for the operations it is supposed to represent), it has to be done using strings and/or `HoldForm`. Here is one way:

First I define the expression to be transformed:

```
expr = a*u''[x]+b*u'[x];
```

Then define the formatting of a variable `dOp` that is supposed to represent the differential operator or its powers. This is done using `Format` - for the first power and `i`-th powers separately.

```
ClearAll[dOp, i];

Power[dOp, i_] ^:= dOp[i];

Format[dOp] = "d/dx";

Format[dOp[i_]] := "d" <> # <> "/dx" <> # &[ToString[i]];

HoldForm[(#) u[x]] &[expr /. u -> (Exp[dOp #] &) /. x -> 0]
```

> `(b d/dx+a d2/dx2) u[x]`

The last instruction takes `expr` and replaces `u` by an exponential function whose derivative with respect to `x` can then be calculated and yields appropriate powers of `dOp`. The above formatting then kicks in and gets applied to these powers.

At that stage, we have the form `(b d/dx+a d2/dx2)`. Lastly, the function `u[x]` has to be put back at the end. This is done by the left-most part of the last line, `HoldForm[(#) u[x]]&` which then wraps the differential operator so that the order is maintained with `u[x]` on the right-hand side of the output. The `HoldForm` is added last because the previous manipulations wouldn't work if carried out inside of `HoldForm`.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much.

Comment: OK, since it works for you I added some explanations, too...