# Customizing display of partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, boxes

I am manipulating partial differential equations symbolically, and would like to get the easily readable form $\rho \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$, leaving variables implicit.

Based on suggestions from [How to make traditional output for derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives) I started out with

```
Derivative /: 
  MakeBoxes[Derivative[α__][f1_][vars__Symbol], TraditionalForm] := 
    Module[{bb, dd, sp},
      MakeBoxes[dd, _] ^= 
      If[Length[{α}] == 1, "\[DifferentialD]", "∂"];
      MakeBoxes[sp, _] ^= "\[ThinSpace]";
      bb /: MakeBoxes[bb[x__], _] := RowBox[Map[ToBoxes[#] &, {x}]];
      TemplateBox[{ToBoxes[bb[dd^Plus[α], f1]], 
      ToBoxes[Apply[bb, 
        Riffle[Map[bb[dd, #] &, 
        Select[({vars}^{α}), (# =!= 1 &)]], sp]]], 
        ToBoxes[Derivative[α][f1][vars]]}, "ShortFraction", 
        DisplayFunction :> (FractionBox[#1, #2] &), 
        InterpretationFunction :> (#3 &), 
        Tooltip -> Automatic]]
```

When functions appear outside of partial derivatives, they still appear as $v(t,x)$. Trying to fix this, I tried

```
supressVariable[f_Symbol] := 
  f /: MakeBoxes[f[t, x], TraditionalForm] :=
    InterpretationBox[ToBoxes[f], f[t, x]]
SetAttributes[supressVariable, Listable]
supressVariable[{v, ρ, p, f}];
```

This works fine for both

```
f[t, x] v[t, x] == 0 // TraditionalForm
```

and

```
ρ[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][v][t, x] + 
   v[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][ρ][t, x] + 
   Derivative[1, 0][ρ][t, x] == 0 // TraditionalForm
```

producing nicely readable equations. However, the simple

```
f[t, x] == 0 // TraditionalForm
```

gives error message

> An unknown box name (ToBoxes) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression

and I don't know what to do with this. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I can't resist pointing out that *suppress* is written with two *p*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that using `MakeBoxes` in this case is overkill. How about this simpler definition?

```
supressVariable[f_Symbol] := 
 Format[f[t, x], TraditionalForm] := Interpretation[f, f[t, x]]

SetAttributes[supressVariable, Listable]
supressVariable[{v, ρ, p, f}];
```

This doesn't encounter the issue you faced, because the symbol `f` is passed directly to `Interpretation` (no need to wrap it in `ToBoxes` at all).

Comment: Be aware that `MakeBoxes` can have superior behavior to `Format` in some ways.  See this Q&A: [(4112299)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Are you saying that there is anything wrong with `Format` in the context of this question? Note that the question is only about formatting for `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: You're right; since TraditionalForm is not for editing anyway I guess my concern is baseless.  I merely got in the habit of using `MakeBoxes` preferentially to `Format` most of the time.  +1

Answer (score 5):

[`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpretationBox.html) holds its arguments (it has [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAllComplete.html)).  You must evaluate `ToBoxes[f]` outside of this head, easily accomplished with [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) as follows:

```
supressVariable[f_Symbol] := 
  f /: MakeBoxes[f[t, x], TraditionalForm] :=
    InterpretationBox[#, f[t, x]] & @ ToBoxes[f]
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more explicit on how it works?

Comment: Actually I think it needs to be made listable

Comment: @chris This isn't complete code; it is to replace only that one "line" in the OP's code.  By default a `Function` will evaluate its arguments; consider:  `Hold[#, 2 + 2] &[1 + 1]`

Comment: Yes, this solution works well. Seeing this, I don't understand how my original attempt worked at all, though.