# Einstein summation and traditional form of partial derivative of implicit function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, customization

I am quite new in Mathematica (1 week new) and after many trials I did not manage to make my partial derivatives to look traditional way.

There are few topics such as [How to make traditional output for derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives) and [Customizing display of partial differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/customizing-display-of-partial-differential-equations) answering this question, but in my case all proposed methods does not give desirable result.

Want this: $\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}$

Have this: $u_x^{(0,0,1)}(x,0,z) + ...$ or $\frac{\partial uv[[1]]} {\partial xz[[1]]}+...$

I would like to expand equation $n_l u_k C_{ijkl} u_{i,j}$. For this purpose I am doing sum over all 4 $ijkl$ indices and result looks as I want but partial derivatives

Code that I am using:

```
nv = {nx, 0, nz};
uv = {ux[x, 0, z], 0, uz[x, 0, z]};
xz = {x, 0, z};
CC = Array[C_{ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString@ {#1, #2, #3, #4}} &, {3, 3, 3, 3}];

(* _{ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString@ {#1, #2, #3, #4}} stands for a subscript of C *)

ux /: Format[ux[___]] := ux;
uz /: Format[uz[___]] := uz;

TraditionalForm[Sum[Part[nv, l] Part[uv, k] Part[CC, i, j, k, l] D[Part[uv, i], Part[xz, j]], {i, {1, 3}}, {j, {1, 3}}, {k, {1, 3}}, {l, {1, 3}}]]
```

If you have any ideas I am grateful in advance

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have you seen this?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited my answer in the [linked thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/245) so that it
can now be used without modification. Previously, you had to define the functions `uv` that you wish to differentiate in a more general way, replacing the explicit `0` in their argument with `y`. The reason is that my earlier answer assumed differentiations are performed on the given function, not on the new function obtained by setting one function argument equal to a constant.

However, now it works with the unchanged definitions in the question (except that I corrected a formatting error in your `CC`):

```
nv = {nx, 0, nz};
uv = {ux[x, 0, z], 0, uz[x, 0, z]};
xz = {x, 0, z};
CC = Array[
   Subscript[C, 
     ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString@{#1, #2, #3, #4}] &, {3, 3,
     3, 3}];

ux /: Format[ux[___]] := ux;
uz /: Format[uz[___]] := uz;

TraditionalForm[
 Sum[Part[nv, l] Part[uv, k] Part[CC, i, j, k, l] D[Part[uv, i], 
    Part[xz, j]], {i, {1, 3}}, {j, {1, 3}}, {k, {1, 3}}, {l, {1, 3}}]]
```

[image: output 2]