# Formatting output for readability

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to suppress the argument `[0, 0, 0, 0]` of `K` in the output of

```
Normal[Series[
   K[(Subscript[x, 0] - Subscript[x, 0] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 0] 0, (Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 1] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 1] 0, (Subscript[x, 2] - Subscript[x, 2] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 2] 0, (Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 3] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 3] 0], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
```

> [image: Out]

Comment: You probably want  the derivative to look nice. (basing on your last question). Try [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/5478)

Comment: I think that the superscript notation is better in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Normal[Series[
   K[(Subscript[x, 0] - Subscript[x, 0] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 0] 0, (Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 1] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 1] 0, (Subscript[x, 2] - Subscript[x, 2] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 2] 0, (Subscript[x, 3] - Subscript[x, 3] 0) t + 
     Subscript[x, 3] 0], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1

% /. K_[0, 0, 0, 0] -> K
```

> [image: Out]

Comment: What does the underscore mean?

Comment: @simon The underscore is called `Blank` in Wolfram Language and it stands for *any expression*. You could also use `% /. whatever_[0, 0, 0, 0] -> whatever` to get the same output. This [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html) gives a nice introduction to the basics of pattern.