# Formatting derivatives in traditional output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting

This is related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives), but goes a bit further. I have also seen [Vitalyi's Blog Post on the topic](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/). I, on the other hand, have used a modified version of Pekka Janhunen's [DFormat package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4576/) to provide a more "traditional" appearance for derivatives. I think the package has advantages over both of the solutions provided at the first two links above, but perhaps the advantages/disadvantages can be combined to get the best of all worlds. One advantage of the code shown in [Jens' post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives) is that it provides a different symbol for ordinary derivatives (of functions of a single variable) versus partial ones.

The `DFormat` code I am using right now is as follows:

```
BeginPackage["PJ`DFormat`"]

DFormat::usage =
"DFormat lets you control the appearance of partial derivatives
within expressions. DFormat[On] turns formatting on, DFormat[NoVars]
turns formatting on but with no variables explicitly displayed,
DFormat[Off] restores the original Mathematica behavior.
DFormat[On] is the default after loading this package."

NoVars::usage ="DFormat[NoVars] sets derivative formatting on
but with no variables."

Begin["`Private`"]

dsign = If[$System === "Macintosh", "6", "\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]"]

denomList[nn_List,vars_List]:=
  Block[{i,result = {}},
    Do[Which[
        TrueQ[nn[[i]]==0], Null,
        TrueQ[nn[[i]]==1], result = Join[result,{dsign,vars[[i]]}],
        True, result = Join[result,{dsign,Superscript[vars[[i]],nn[[i]]]}] ],
       {i,1,Length[nn]} ];
    result]

DFormat[Off]:=
(Unprotect[Derivative];
Format[Literal[Derivative[nn__][ff_][vars:(_Symbol ..)]]]=.;
Protect[Derivative])

DFormat[On]:=
(Unprotect[Derivative];
Format[Literal[Derivative[nn__][ff_][vars:(_Symbol ..)]]]:=
  If[TrueQ[Plus@@{nn} == 1],
     SequenceForm[dsign,ff[vars]],
     SequenceForm[Superscript[dsign,Plus@@{nn}],ff[vars]]]/
  SequenceForm @@ denomList[{nn},{vars}];
Protect[Derivative])

DFormat[NoVars]:=
(Unprotect[Derivative];
Format[Literal[Derivative[nn__][ff_][vars:(_Symbol ..)]]]:=
  If[TrueQ[Plus@@{nn} == 1],
     SequenceForm[dsign,ff(*[vars]*)],
     SequenceForm[Superscript[dsign,Plus@@{nn}],ff(*[vars]*)]]/
  SequenceForm @@ denomList[{nn},{vars}];
Protect[Derivative])

End[]

EndPackage[]

DFormat[On]

Null
```

This works fine for what it does, with one exception: If I have a derivative of a function of a single variable, I would like to see the `DifferentialD` operator instead of the `PartialD` one that is used with this package.  I realize that this may be possible with a near-trivial change of the code below, but I just haven't been able to get this to work. There's also some minor quibbles with the typesetting of expressions such as

```
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 3}]
```

which gives a `TraditionalForm` output that looks like so:

[image]

If you are fussy about things like that you will notice that the second `PartialD` in the denominator is a bit too close to the x^2, and a bit too far from the y^3. One might also want the `PartialD^5` in the numerator a bit closer to the f there.