# How to change output style of mathematical expressions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting

For example I have output from function like that:
[image]

How to change style of output to smth like that?

[image]

I have tried `TraditionalForm`, but still have no result.
[image]

Comment: @Nasser it doesn't help with the main goal: reformat derivatives. [pic](http://fotohost.by/images/2016/10/08/2016-10-08_22-34-37.png)

Comment: Ok, then please see [mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/)  may be that is what you meant. There are also few questions on this site about changing the traditional format.  [how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives)

Comment: Slightly off topic: _Mathematica_'s `Derivative` function, instead of differentiating with respect to a variable, takes the derivative of a function with respect to the argument. In other words, _Mathematica_ takes the derivative and then plugs in the variable `ξ`.

Comment: @Nasser ty, function from [Mathematica Q&A Series](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/) helped! You can rewrite your comment as answer.