# How to use a convective derivative

Tags: symbolic, vector-calculus

I am trying to figure out how to do a convective derivative in Mathematica in the context of the [Navier-Stokes equation](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/864.11/people/rachelle.villalon/final/ns.jpg). The issue is, I have no clue how dot product a vector with the gradient operator. The below syntax doesn't work. Can anyone provide advice? The specific part of the Navier-Stokes equation I'm having trouble with is the term labeled "acceleration" in the link above.

```
\[Rho] (D[u, t] + Dot[u, \[Del]]*u)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `Del` symbol (which has no built-in meaning) you need the gradient operator. What you're looking for can be achieved by using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) to apply the dot product of $\vec{u}$ and [`Grad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html) to each row of the vector. I define this as the convective derivative `dConvect` and apply it to a test vector `uVec`:

```
uVec = Through[{Subscript[u, \[ScriptX]], Subscript[u, \[ScriptY]], 
     Subscript[u, \[ScriptZ]]}[x, y, z, t]];
dConvect[vec_] := D[vec, t] + ((vec.Grad[#, {x, y, z}]) & /@ vec)
dConvect[uVec] // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

The output is a little ugly, so I'll add some better formatting before displaying the result:

```
Derivative /:MakeBoxes[Derivative[\[Alpha]__][f1_][vars__?AtomQ], 
  TraditionalForm] := 
 Module[{bb, dd, sp}, 
  MakeBoxes[dd, _] ^= 
   If[Length[{\[Alpha]}] == 1, "\[DifferentialD]", "\[PartialD]"];
  MakeBoxes[sp, _] ^= "\[ThinSpace]";
  bb /: MakeBoxes[bb[x__], _] := RowBox[Map[ToBoxes[#] &, {x}]];
  TemplateBox[{ToBoxes[bb[dd^Plus[\[Alpha]], f1]], 
    ToBoxes[Apply[bb, 
      Riffle[Map[
        bb[dd, #] &, (Pick[{vars}, #]^Pick[{\[Alpha]}, #] &[
          Thread[{\[Alpha]} > 0]])], sp]]], 
    ToBoxes[Derivative[\[Alpha]][f1][vars]]}, "ShortFraction", 
   DisplayFunction :> (FractionBox[#1, #2] &), 
   InterpretationFunction :> (#3 &), Tooltip -> Automatic]]

Format[Subscript[u, s_][x, y, z, t]] := Subscript[u, s];

dConvect[uVec] // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image: vec]

The formatting uses [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/245).

Comment: Not sure if I am supposed to do this - but `dConvect` won't find all the terms if I try it in Spherical Coordinates. I wonder how you'd do this?