# Convective derivative in cylindrical coordinate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coordinate-transformation

My question is similar to this one about [convective derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129075/how-to-use-a-convective-derivative). But how do I adapt it to the cylindrical coordinate? Simply changing `Grad` to cylindrical coordinate does not produce correct results, which can be found [here](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2008/08/derivation-of-navier-stokes-equations_17.html), because we need to include the terms with the derivative of the unit vector too.

Here is the adapted code,

```
uVec = Through[{Subscript[u, r], Subscript[u, \[Theta]], 
     Subscript[u, z]}[r, \[Theta], z, t]];
dConvect[vec_] := 
 D[vec, t] + ((vec.Grad[#, {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]) & /@ 
    vec)
dConvect[uVec] // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

which produces the result below.

[image]

Comment: Something like formula 3 [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvectiveOperator.html)?

Comment: yes, will post additional information soon.

Comment: That's a good idea; if you add extra information, users might be persuaded to reopen your question.

Comment: with the added information, can this question be reopened?