# TeXForm handling of derivative higher than two

Tags: output-formatting, latex, conversion

When the expression is only up to second derivative, `TeXForm` works correctly:

```
ode = y''[x] == 0;
TeXForm[ode]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when the order is higher than 2, it does this:

```
ode = y'''[x] == 0;
TeXForm[ode]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which does not look as nice in my $\LaTeX$ report when compiled to PDF.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It can also confuses with thinking it is `y` raised to power of `3` instead of third derivative.

Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* to keep `'''` as is? As in this screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Having to edit this by hand inside my Latex editor is not really an option for many reason. I'd like to do this inside *Mathematica*, when I export the expressions to $\LaTeX$.

My current workflow is this: Use `TeXForm`, convert to string, save to the $\LaTeX$ file, then compile the file to PDF.

Comment: Related: [How to make traditional output for derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23659/245)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat hacky:

```
TeXForm[y'''''[t] + 2 x'''[t] - y'[t] == x[t] /. 
        Derivative[k_Integer][f_] /; k > 2 :> 
        Superscript[f, Symbol[StringJoin[ConstantArray["′", k]]]]]

(* 2 x'''(t)+y'''''(t)-y'(t)=x(t) *)
```

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I forgot that had a Unicode codepoint! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to transforming an expression before applying TeXForm is to modify the TraditionalForm formatting rules for Derivative:

```
Derivative /: MakeBoxes[Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][h_],TraditionalForm] := SuperscriptBox[
    MakeBoxes[h,TraditionalForm],
    StringJoin@ConstantArray["\[Prime]",n]
]
```

Then, TeXForm will use this new FormatValue:

```
TeXForm[y'''''[t] + 2 x'''[t] - y'[t] == x[t]]
```

> 2 x'''(t)+y'''''(t)-y'(t)=x(t)

and ToString[.., TeXForm] as well:

```
ToString[y'''''[t] + 2 x'''[t] - y'[t] == x[t], TeXForm]
```

> 2 x'''(t)+y'''''(t)-y'(t)=x(t)