# Using `Format` to create a notation for derivatives

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to create a new function that I called `HD` to give a visual way to see the derivatives. For example:

The objective is apply the function `HD[f_,x_]`:

```
HD[f_, x_]
```

To obtain:

[image]

What I have at this moment is:

```
Format[HD[f_, x_]] := ("∂" f)/("∂" x)
```

But my result is:

```
In[41]:= HD[f, x]

Out[41]= f/x
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23659/5478

Comment: If linked question does not help, let me know why. Would also be nice to respond to comments under your recent questions.

Comment: The link helps me, thanks. Sorry to respond too late.