# Function to change derivative notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, custom-notation

I would like to write a function to change the notation of derivative in an expression. For instance, the function `rep` will take `Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t]` and output `diff[F[x,y,z,t],z]`:

`rep[Derivative[0, 0, 1, 1][F][x, y, z, t]] =  diff[F[x,y,z,t],z,t]`.

Any help to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: But `F^(0,0,1,0)[x,y,z,t]` itself is not valid syntax. What is exactly the problem you are trying to solve? i.e. why do you need to do this in first place?

Comment: That's the plain text form of the output of D[F[x,y,z,t],z].

Comment: `That's the plain text form of the output of D[F[x,y,z,t],z]` On my version of Mathematica, this is the plain text of `D[F[x,y,z,t],z]` I get `InputForm[D[F[x, y, z, t], z]]` gives `Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t]`  so how did it come to be `F^(0,0,1,0)[x,y,z,t]` on your end? Since this is not valid mathematica syntax. It gives error `Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "0,0,1,0)".` I am using V 12.1., which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: (F^(0,1,0,0))[x,y,t,z] - output copied as plain text.

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: I see where the confusion. What you see on the screen is not the actual code. To see the actual code, you need to use `InputForm`. That is what is read by Mathematica. Screen thing is just formatting for display purposes only. So your question should be `How to change Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t] to diff[F[x,y,z,t],z]` that is all. (but what is `diff`? Is this your own function?

Comment: If your purpose is for display only, then here is the answer  [how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives/23664#23664)  Notice that `D[F[x, y, z, t], z]` is really `Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t]`.  Try `D[F[x, y, z, t], z]// InputForm` to see.

Comment: You are right. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what is wanted:

```
rep[Derivative[ords__][f_][args__]] /; Length[{ords}] == Length[{args}] := 
    diff[f[args], ##] & @@ Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray, {{args}, {ords}}]]
```

For instance,

```
rep[Derivative[0, 2, 0, 1][F][x, y, z, w]]
   diff[F[x, y, z, w], y, y, w]

rep[Derivative[0, 0, 1, 1][F][x, y, z, w]]
   diff[F[x, y, z, w], z, w]
```

Comment: very nice. I did not know one could do it that way, i.e. write it as `Derivative[ords__][f_][args__]`. Makes it much easier to pick up the items I wanted instead of using indexing.

Comment: Of course, this fails if `Derivative[ords][f]` auto-evaluates to something that no longer has `Derivative[]`. ;) Otherwise, it works well for OP's specific examples.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I think my code will also fail if the input does not have same structure as well, as it uses fixed indexing assuming same structure. I think I will have to remember your method from now on. Makes doing some things I wanted to do much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

> function rep will take Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t] and
>   output diff[F[x,y,z,t],z]:

Just a quick hack, as I do not know of direct MMA command. Will let someone else come up with a one liner answer ;)

```
ClearAll[F, x, y, z, t];
rep[f_, g_] := Module[{h, vars = {}, n, i, deps = {}},
  h = f[[0, 1]];
  n = Length@f[[0, 0]];
  Do[
   If[(f[[0, 0]][[i]]) == 1, AppendTo[deps, f[[i]]]];
   AppendTo[vars, f[[i]]]
   , {i, 1, n}];

  g[h[Sequence @@ vars], Sequence @@ deps]
  ]
```

Call as

```
 rep[Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][F][x, y, z, t], diff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 rep[Derivative[0, 0, 1, 1][F][x, y, z, t], diff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 rep[Derivative[1, 0, 1, 0][F][x, y, z, t], diff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not sure how are you going to use this result, but this is what you asked for.