# Symbolic Jacobian computation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have an equation for which I would like to compute the Jacobian symbolically.

$$f(x)=Ax-diag(x)(Ax+b)$$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am new to Mathematica, and I have seen [this relevant question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/how-to-make-jacobian-automatically-in-mathematica), but I am not aware of how to automatically ensure Mathematica recognises the different dimensions. Can someone help me how to code that in Mathematica?

Comment: Just to clarify, are $n$, $A$, and $b$ unknown symbolic constants?

Comment: Yes @MichaelE2...

Comment: You posted another question, but formulated the problem differently. I assume it is the same problem in both questions?

Comment: @Wojciech: Same equation, but I need the zeros in the other question. Here it is the Jacobian.

Answer (score 4):

Define the elements and the function f:

```
n=2;
aMat = Array[a, {n, n}];
xVec = Array[x, n];
bVec = Array[b, n];
f[xVec_] := aMat.xVec - DiagonalMatrix[xVec].(aMat.xVec + bVec);
```

The Jacobian is:

```
D[f[xVec], {xVec}]
MatrixForm[%]
```

[image]

It seems to work fine for fairly large values of `n`.

Comment: just to note the `JacobianMatrix` defined in the linked answer works fine with these defs `JacobianMatrix[f[xVec], xVec]`  - now what would be really nice is to do this symbolically (i.e. w/o pre defining the matrix terms)