# Factor vector out of a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation, vector

I am wondering how to factor `a[1],a[2],...,a[4]` out of `sim` so that I can write `sim` as the form of a matrix times column vector `a`.    (`a[1],a[2],...,a[4]` are the component of vector `a`) ?

My ultimate goal is to compute the `Omega` when the determinant of the matrix is zero.

```
Nmax = 4;
x[0][t] = 0;
x[Nmax + 1][t] = 0;

T = 1/2 Sum[m[i] x[i]'[t]^2, {i, 1, Nmax}];
U = 1/2 Sum[k[i] (x[i][t] - x[i - 1][t])^2, {i, 1, Nmax + 1}];

L = T - U;

EL[q_] := D[L, q] - D[D[L, D[q, t]], t]

eigen = Table[EL[x[i][t]], {i, 1, Nmax}] // MatrixForm;

x[i_][t_] = a[i] E^(I \[Omega] t);

sim = eigen /. t -> 0
```

[image]

Comment: @b.gatessucks And then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the linear relationship, you can simply get the desired matrix by calculating the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), as follows:

```
matrix = D[sim, {Array[a, Nmax]}];
```

The Jacobi matrix is by definition the linear approximation to a (differentiable) multivariate function. Here, the variables `a[1]...a[4]` are therefore used as the independent variables. It's important to have these variables as a list of the form `{{a[1]... a[4]}}` (two `List` levels) to get the derivatives arranged in the form of a matrix the way it has to be for the Jacobian. See also the question [How to make Jacobian automatically in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5790/245).

What follows is just the verification that the result is correct:

```
Simplify[matrix.Array[a, Nmax] == sim]

(* ==> True *)

MatrixForm[matrix]
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I'm still confused about the math behind the method you used here. Can you tell me which exactly part of knowledge it is or just direct me to a math page that illustrate this method?

Comment: And it seems unnecessary for the second line code `Simplify[matrix.Array[a, Nmax] == sim]` to be here, because I take it out and I can still get the desired matrix. What's the point of putting it here?

Comment: @Lawerance I added a link for you. The `Simplify` line is there to prove to you that the task has been accomplished. Only the first line is needed.