# Differentiation of an unknown function

Tags: complex, differentials, calculus-and-analysis

I have to take the partial differentiation of an unknown function.
For example, take the unknown function to be $g(x)$. Then it's derivative w.r.t $x$ is $g'(x)$.

By default, *Mathematica* differentiates the function. I want to keep the result of differentiation as $d(g(x))$ and not $g'(x)$. Is there any way to achieve this?

More precisely, I am using `Conjugate[g[x]]` as the unknown function and I want the output should be displayed only as `d[Conjugate[g[x]]` and not as `Conjugate'[x]g'[x]`.

Also, can I handle the conjugate more efficiently than just carrying it all along in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited because the goal was changed in the comment:**

This can be done by directly defining the outcome of `Derivative` when applied to `g` in the two combinations that you seem to be interested in:

```
Derivative[1][g][x_] := d[g[x]]

Derivative[1][Conjugate][g[x_]] := Conjugate[d[g[x]]]/d[g[x]];
Derivative[1][Conjugate][d[x_]] := Conjugate[d[d[x]]]/d[d[x]]

Derivative[1][d][x_] := d[d[x]]/d[x];
Derivative[1][d][x_Symbol] := d[d[x]]
```

On the second line, I used the fact that `g` is a generic function whose derivative under a `Conjugate` by default invokes the chain rule. All I do then is to *reverse* the chain rule by dividing by the factor `d[g[x]]` that the chain rule will produce. This leaves only the factor I want, and I then replace that by the desired outcome `d[Conjugate[g[x]]]`.

The analogous thing is done for `d` to allow higher derivatives. The exception is when `d[x]` is encountered where `x` is the differentiation variable (which isn't in the question, but I expect may happen). Then there is no chain rule needed, and I therefore specify a separate rule for it with the pattern `x_Symbol`.

Here is the test:

```
D[g[x], x]

(* ==> d[g[x]] *)

D[Conjugate[g[x]], x]

(* ==> d[Conjugate[g[x]]] *)

D[g[x], x, x]

(* ==> d[d[g[x]]] *)

D[d[g[x]], x]

(* ==> d[d[g[x]]] *)

D[d[x], x]

(* ==> d[d[x]] *)

D[Conjugate[g[x]], x]

(* ==> Conjugate[d[g[x]]] *)

D[Conjugate[g[x]], x, x]

(* ==> Conjugate[d[d[g[x]]]] *)
```

Now the remaining issue is to replace the repeated application of `d` by formatting of the type `d^2 g[x]` for `d[d[g[x]]]`. I'll wait to see if this is really desired before doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is exactly what I need. Can you please modify the output of D[Conjugate[g[x]], x] as Conjugate[d[g[x]] and not as d[Conjugate[g[x]]] .
You are free to change the above mentioned approach of yours if needed.
Anyways, Many Many thanks for your input.

Comment: You just hve to do this: `Derivative[1][Conjugate][g[x_]] := Conjugate[d[g[x]]]/d[g[x]]` (but that's not what you asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks. This serves my purpose well. Can you please also help me with obtaining the double derivative of g[x] and Conjugate[g[x]] as d^2 g[x] and Conjugate[d^2[g[x]]]. I tried it all this time but I am unable to obtain the above desired representation.

Comment: What you're asking now is very different from the original question because it aims for a new formatting that is inconsistent with *Mathematica* syntax (because of the squares). It would  require box-level manipulations as I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5792/245).

Answer (score 4):

If it is just the displayed form you are after, you can also go with `HoldForm` like so:

```
HoldForm@D[Conjugate[g[x]],x]
```

[image: unevaluated]

This will carry over throughout the notebook without further ado, until you call `ReleaseHold` on it.

I hope this might be of some help to you.