# Working with derivative of conjugate of a complex number

Tags: functions, evaluation, symbolic, complex

I have a complex function, lets say $g(x)$. I want to take its and its conjugate's derivative. I need the solution of derivative which must be symbolically and computationally efficient.
Lets take an example:

```
Derivative[1][g][x_] := d[g[x]]

Derivative[1][Conjugate][g[x_]] := Conjugate[d[g[x]]]/d[g[x]];
Derivative[1][Conjugate][d[x_]] := Conjugate[d[d[x]]]/d[d[x]]

Derivative[1][d][x_] := d[d[x]]/d[x];
Derivative[1][d][x_Symbol] := d[d[x]]
```

This will give me an effective symbolic representation of the derivative of $g(x)$ and $Conjugate(g(x))$ as `d[g[x]]` and `Conjugate[d[g[x]]]` but when I have to plug the analytical complex expression of $g(x)$ in `d[g[x]]`, it will not compute the derivative of $g(x)$ instead gives only the symbolic representation of $d(g(x))$, which is computationally inefficient.
Is something can be done which is capable of symbolic as well as algebraic computation.

P.S. I do need the symbolic representation of the derivatives of conjugate in the above format only.

Comment: Very closely related: [Differentiation of an unknown function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75873/245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following two constructs to your advantage, which will keep the `Conjugate`, but evaluate and simplify the derivative inside. Using `ReleaseHold`, you can then evaluate even the `Conjugate`.

Note that I left out the divisor in the `Conjugate`-case for clarity, but you can easily add that into the second function's definition.

```
d[g_] := Derivative[1][g]
d[Conjugate[g_]] := With[{dg = d[g]@# // Simplify},
                      HoldForm[Conjugate[dg]] &]

(* example function *)
g[x_] := TrigToExp@Sin[x]

(* evaluation *)
d[g][x]
(* \[ExponentialE]^(-\[ImaginaryI] x)/2+
      \[ExponentialE]^(\[ImaginaryI] x)/2 *)

d[Conjugate[g]][x]
(* Conjugate[1/2 \[ExponentialE]^(-\[ImaginaryI] x)
      (1+\[ExponentialE]^(2 \[ImaginaryI] x))] *)
```

---

### Update

If you want further derivatives, you can instead use this slight expansion of the idea above:

```
d[g_, n_:1] := Derivative[n][g]
d[Conjugate[g_], n_:1] := With[{dg = d[g, n]@# // Simplify}, HoldForm[Conjugate[dg]] &]
```

`n` gives the order of derivation you want. If left out, the first derivative is generated.

**Interesting sidenote:** `n` can even be *negative*, giving you the integral of your function. Observe e.g.:

```
h[x_]:=Sin[x]
d[h,0][x]       (* Sin[x] *)

d[h,-1][x]      (* -Cos[x] *)

d[h,1][x]       (* Cos[x] *)
d[h][x]         (* Cos[x] *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please tell me, where to read from to understand such programming in mathematica in a better way? I couldn't find this type of programming in any textbooks.

Comment: @ShivamSahu: I can only speak for myself: I learned the little I know about *Mathematica* from its documentation and my own humble experiments.  If my answer helped in your quest, please "accept" it.

Comment: I have one more question. How can we handle double derivative of g(x) and Conjugate(g(x)) with this?

Comment: @ShivamSahu: Have a look at the update I made to my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. This was precisely what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @ShivamSahu: Glad to hear that!