# Derivative of conjugate multivariate function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a problem with Mathematica, taking the derivative of the conjugate of some function. I know that a similar question has been posed before [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77481/working-with-derivative-of-conjugate-of-a-complex-number), but the solution did not work for multivariate function.

Problem is:
I try to evaluate

```
D[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]], x]
```

And get the result

```
Conjugate'[f[x, y, z]] f^(1, 0, 0)[x, y, z]
```

But would like

```
Conjugate[f^(1, 0, 0)[x, y, z]]
```

where ^ is supposed to be superscript. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: `MapAt[D[#, x] &, Conjugate[f[x, y, z]], 1]` or `Map[D[#, x] &, Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]]` or `D[#, x] & /@ Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]`.

Answer (score 19):

There are System options one can set to control the behavior of `D`. One of these is the "ExcludedFunctions" option:

```
excluded="ExcludedFunctions"/.
    ("DifferentiationOptions"/.SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"])
```

> {Hold,HoldComplete,Less,LessEqual,Greater,GreaterEqual,Inequality,Unequal,Nand,Nor,Xor,Not,Element,Exists,ForAll,Implies,Positive,Negative,NonPositive,NonNegative,Replace,ReplaceAll,ReplaceRepeated}

These are functions that D will not differentiate. We can add Conjugate to this list by using:

```
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->
    "ExcludedFunctions"->Union[excluded,{Conjugate}]]
```

> DifferentiationOptions->{AlwaysThreadGradients->False,DifferentiateHeads->True,DifferentiateIteratorIndexed->True,DirectHighDerivatives->True,DirectHighDerivativeThreshold->10,ExcludedFunctions->{Conjugate,Element,Exists,ForAll,Greater,GreaterEqual,Hold,HoldComplete,Implies,Inequality,Less,LessEqual,Nand,Negative,NonNegative,NonPositive,Nor,Not,Positive,Replace,ReplaceAll,ReplaceRepeated,Unequal,Xor},ExitOnFailure->False,HighDerivativeMaxTerms->1000,SymbolicAutomaticDifferentiation->False}

Now, `D` will not try to differentiate `Conjugate`:

```
D[Conjugate[f[x]], x]//InputForm
```

> D[Conjugate[f[x]], x]

We are now free to give `D` rules for differentiating `Conjugate`:

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], x__] := Conjugate[D[f, x]]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

Let's see what happens to the OP example now:

```
D[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]], x]
```

> Conjugate[Derivative[1][f][x]]

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
Conjugate[f[x_, y_, z_]] ^:= cf[x, y, z]

Derivative[d__][cf][x__] := Conjugate[Derivative[d][f][x]]

D[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]], x]
```

> `Conjugate[Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]]`

All I did here is to define the derivative of the function `f` to be another function `cf` which then can be given the property you want.

Comment: Is the `^` before the `:=` a typo?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform No, it's `UpSetDelayed`.

Comment: Oh, that's a new one for me, cool. Thanks!

Comment: Just a last question, as this is going to be very helpful for me. If we take `cf[x,y,z] =-E^(-2 I x) + 2 E^(-I y - I z) + 2 E^(-3 I z - I x) + 
 12 E^(-2 I y - 2 I x)`. It doesn't work. I'm sure I'm missing something ?

Comment: @Shamina `cf` is supposed to remain purely symbolic. I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `=` assignment. Even if you change that to `cf[x_,y_,z_] := ...` it wouldn't correspond to what this question was originally about. You may have to ask a new question.

Comment: This solution is handy only if we have one function at hand: if we have another function g[x,y], we need to write the first 2 lines again replacing f[x,y,z] for g[x,y].