# Derivative of Sign[x]

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) the derivative of the Sign[x] function has the following property:

$\qquad \frac{d}{dx}{\rm Sign}[x]=2\delta[x]$

Where $\delta[x]={\rm DiracDelta}[x]$. It seems that Mathematica ignores this property. If I'm not wrong about this, is there a way to assign this property globally (for all Notebook cells)?

Comment: That's a "delta", not a "theta". It refers to Dirac's delta function. The relationship you cite is valid only for real numbers, while `Sign` works for all complex ones.

Comment: BTW you can always define your own: `Clear[realSign];
realSign[0] = 0;
realSign[x_] := -1 /; x < 0;
realSign[x_] := 1 /; x > 0;
realSign' = 2 DiracDelta[#] &`

Comment: Why not use `sign[x_] := 2 HeavisideTheta[x] - 1` instead? You can also use the technique I provided in [(137443)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137443/45431)

Comment: You can simply override this behaviour: `Unprotect[Derivative];
Derivative[1][Sign][x_Symbol] := 2*DiracDelta[x]
Protect[Derivative];` but i suggest to implement your own sign function which behaves like that suggested by Carl Woll

Comment: @Julien Kluge Your suggestion doesn't work for D[Sign[f[x]], x]. If you want to change how Sign is differentiated, it is better to use the technique in the  link I mention above.

Comment: Note that in Mathematica 11.1 there is a RealSign function that behaves as expected.