# Conjugate & Derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have some problem with the derivative of the 'conjugate' expression:
Here I define the functions:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + I y;
g[x_, y_] := x + 3 I y y;
h[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][f[#, #2]\[Conjugate]/g[#, #2] &][x, y]
```

When I try to evaluate one of the expression, for example

```
h[1, 1]
```

I got something like

```
Derivative[1][Conjugate][1 + I]
```

which is not true. 
   If I try the code suggested in [Derivative of conjugate multivariate function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91356/derivative-of-conjugate-multivariate-function)

```
 excluded = 
 "ExcludedFunctions" /. ("DifferentiationOptions" /. 
    SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"])
SetSystemOptions[
 "DifferentiationOptions" -> 
  "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union[excluded, {Conjugate}]]
```

I got the error

```
  General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.
```

Comment: I usually DIY my own "conjugate" by an explicit replacement rule.

Comment: Could you please show this on the example written above

Comment: I decided so because I think it not good enough to be posted.

Comment: Well, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I am sorry, the old answer does not work, but it seems that the rule cannot be applied to pure functions.

A working way is, provided that all symbols are deemed real, which is what `ComplexExpand` does:

```
f[x_, y_] = ComplexExpand[ (*Expressions containing Conjugate*) ];
h[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][f[#, #2]/g[#, #2] &][x, y]

h[x, y]
h[1, 1]
```

> ```
> -((6 I (x - I y) y)/(x + 3 I y^2)^2) - I/(x + 3 I y^2)
>
> -(9/50) + (37 I)/50
> ```

---

**Old**

It is long since I made the observation that *Mathematica* seems not to know what to do when `Conjugate` meets `D`.

Comment: thx. I have already noticed that your first suggested example gives the wrong answer. Will your second example decrease the calculation rate? I have a very large amount of functions and need to do rather complex calculations. Is it possible not to replace all the functions like 'f[x,y]\[Conjugate]'  by 'Evaluate[ComplexExpand[f[x, y]\[Conjugate]]]'?

Comment: @Chipa-Chipa Then I suggest that you do not use a pure function in the middle of `Derivative`, but use the explicit form of the function you want to go further.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make the replacement only when I define the derivative?

Comment: @Chipa-Chipa I mean to obtain the explicit expression of the function, before you put it into its derivative calculation.

Comment: I think the problem with your original way was a misplaced `Evaluate`.  Try `myConjugate = # /. {I -> -I, -I -> I} &;
h[x_, y_] := 
 Derivative[0, 1][Evaluate[myConjugate[f[#, #2]]/g[#, #2]] &][x, y]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great! Thx for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Here are three similar ways.  The first seems best (simplest) to me:

```
ClearAll[h];
Block[{x, y},
 h[x_, y_] = D[ComplexExpand[f[x, y]\[Conjugate]/g[x, y]], y];
 ]

h[x, y] // Simplify
(*  -((I (x + 6 x y - 3 I y^2))/(x + 3 I y^2)^2)  *)
```

The following one generates message every time `h[x, y]` is evaluated, but it seems to give the correct answer.  The reason for the messages is interesting.  It implies a potential pitfall in using `ComplexExpand`: It appears the internal code for `ComplexExpand[]` creates a function with `&` using its arguments.  The `Slot[]` expressions in `f[#, #2]` and `g[#, #2]` get caught up in this and lead to error messages; but the internal code seems to recover in this case.  (Perhaps it should be considered a bug?)

```
ClearAll[h];
h[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][Evaluate@ComplexExpand[f[#, #2]\[Conjugate]/g[#, #2]] &][x, y]
```

One could also do something like this:

```
ClearAll[h];
h[x_, y_] := 
 Derivative[0, 1][
   Block[{xx, yy}, 
    Function[{xx, yy}, 
     Evaluate@ComplexExpand[f[xx, yy]\[Conjugate]/g[xx, yy]]]]][x, y];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround.  Looks like the Derivative format doesn't like conjugate, but this seems to work:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + I y;
g[x_, y_] := x + 3 I y y;

h[x_, y_] := D[Conjugate[f[x, yy]]/g[x, yy], yy] /. yy -> y

h[1, 1] // ComplexExpand
(*-(9/50) + (37 I)/50*)
```

Comment: Hi, this code failed in v13.

Comment: @lotus2019 Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. In v13.0, the result is `3/25 + 1/10 Im[Derivative[1][Conjugate][1]] + 
 I (21/25 - 3/10 Im[Derivative[1][Conjugate][1]] - 
    1/10 Re[Derivative[1][Conjugate][1]]) - 
 3/10 Re[Derivative[1][Conjugate][1]]`

Comment: @lotus2019 I don't have v13.0, but in v13.2.1, the output is as I have it.

Comment: OK, it seems that I need to upgrade the version. Thank you for your reply.