# How to create a big jacobian matrix function over some variables of a vector function?

Tags: function-construction

Suppose I have a vector function of $n$ components and it has $n+m$ arguments,

$$\vec{f}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n, y_1, y_2, \dots, y_{m})$$

where $n, m $ are around 10. I want to create a Jacobian matrix over $\vec{x}$ only, 
$$J_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j},$$
and then use it as a function.
However, since I have a lots of arguments, it is really messy easy to make mistake when I create the table. For example, $n=10$ and $m=5$, then $J_{6,5}$ is

```
J[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_,x6_,x7_,x8_,x9_,x10_,y1_,y2_,y3_,y4_,y5_][[6,5]]:=Derivative[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0][f][x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5][[6]]
```

which is a nightmare for me. How to do it in a more efficient way such that I don't have to deal with all the arguments?

The operation D[{f1,f2,...},{{x1,x2,...}}] does not work, like,

```
u1[x1_, x2_] := x1*x2; 
u2[x1_, x2_] := x1 - x2; 
J[x1_, x2_] := D[{u1[x1, x2], u2[x1, x2]}, {{x1, x2}}]; 
J[1, 1]
```

it returns error

```
General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `Differentiation`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Since I am defining a function, which is 
J[x1_,x2_ ....] = ... 
that way of creating the function is problematic

Comment: You can just do `D[{f1, f2, f3}, {{x1, x2, x3, x4}}]`.

Comment: For example,  
    u1[x1_, x2_] := x1*x2;
    u2[x1_, x2_] := x1 - x2;
    J[x1_, x2_] := D[{u1[x1, x2], u2[x1, x2]}, {{x1, x2}}];
    J[1, 1]

it returns error General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>

Comment: Also, that is just part of my problem. I have many arguments, is there a simple way of storing the arguments ?

Comment: You can define `vars={x1, x2, ...}` and then do `D[{f1, f2, ...}, {vars}]`.

Comment: That "D" operation does not work for defining function

Comment: See if [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5791/134) answers your question.

Comment: The same problem with that method is,it calculates the matrix but cannot be used to define a matrix function. Could you please have a look on my updated question ? thank you very much !