# Computing Jacobian matrix

Tags: syntax, vector-calculus

I am trying to compute the [Jacobian matrix J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). In my case, f and x are 3-vectors (my vectors are named g and a instead), so J should be a 3X3 matrix.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
a = {{a1}, {a2}, {a3}} // MatrixForm
g = {{Subscript[l, 1]*Cos[a1] + Subscript[l, 2]*Cos[a1 + a2] + 
     Subscript[l, 3]*Cos[a1 + a2 + a3]}, {Subscript[l, 1]*Sin[a1] + 
     Subscript[l, 2]*Sin[a1 + a2] + Subscript[l, 3]*Sin[a1 + a2 + a3]},
   {a1 + a2 + a3}   } //   MatrixForm 
J = D[g, a] // MatrixForm
```

This is the output I get in Mathematica:
[image]

Based on the [suggestions from another discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/how-to-make-jacobian-automatically-in-mathematica/5792#5792), I also tried

```
J = D[g, {a}]
```

and

```
J = JacobianMatrix[g, a]
```

but neither worked. Can someone tell me why I'm not getting the correct Jacobian matrix, and share code for the correct method?

Comment: MatrixForm is a display command. Remove it from your defintions of a and g.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but I still don't get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop all the extra { }'s, remove the MatrixForm:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
g = {l1 Cos[a1] + l2 Cos[a1 + a2] + l3 Cos[a1 + a2 + a3], 
   l1 Sin[a1] + l2 Sin[a1 + a2] + l3 Sin[a1 + a2 + a3], a1 + a2 + a3};
j = D[g, {a}];
MatrixForm[j]
```

Comment: Thanks! As you can tell, I'm new to Mathematica :)

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have a notion of row or column, so all the { } were just confusing. Also, the syntax of D[ ] requires the brackets around the second argument (or else it is interpreted as multiple derivatives). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with `MatrixForm` as such but where you're placing it.  You are assigning a value to `a` and `g` containing a MatrixForm, rather than displaying the `MatrixForm` of an assignment.  So the following would work

```
(a = {a1, a2, a3}) // MatrixForm
(g = {l1 Cos[a1] + l2 Cos[a1 +  a2] + l3 Cos[a1 + a2 + a3], 
     l1 Sin[a1] + l2 Sin[a1 + a2] + l3 Sin[a1 + a2 + a3], 
     a1 + a2 + a3}) // MatrixForm
(j = Grad[g, a]) // MatrixForm
```

Also note the use above of the a built-in `Grad` command, that supports arbitrary rank arrays.