# Jacobian matrix evaluation at a point

Tags: matrix, webmathematica

I have a vector function $ f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y) ).$ I need to find the Jacobian matrix for $f$ evaluated at the point $(x,y) = (a,b).$

I learnt that I can use something like the following on Mathematica to find the Jacobian matrix:

Jacobian matrix $(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y) )$ w.r.t. $x$, and $y.$

I need to evaluate the Jacobina matrix at the point $(x,y) = (a,b)$ using Mathematica.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5790/1783

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let f be a vector function:

f[x_, y_] := {f1[x, y], f2[x, y]};

Then the Jacobian is the matrix valued function:

D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]

[image]

and the Jacobian at point {a,b} is:

```
D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] /. {x->a,y->b}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as follows:

Vector field:

```
F[{x_, y_}] := Evaluate[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}]
X = {x, y};
X0 = {a, b};
```

The Jacobian Matrix:

```
J[{x_, y_}] = Simplify[D[F[X], {X}]];
MatrixForm@J[X]
```

[image]

The Jacobian at point $X_{0}=\left(a, b \right)$ is:

```
MatrixForm@J[X0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html) you can take the code as appears there. Namely,

```
JacobianMatrix[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] := 
 Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})

JacobianDeterminant[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] := 
 Det[JacobianMatrix[f, x]] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})
```

The Jacobian matrix is

```
JacobianMatrix[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

> [image: jac1]

and you can evaluate at a point using either of the following:

```
JacobianMatrix[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, y}] /. {x :> a, y :> b}

With[{x = a, y = b}, JacobianMatrix[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, y}]]
```

both return the same result of course

> [image: jac2]

Finally, the command for the Jacobian determinant is very similar

```
JacobianDeterminant[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

> [image: jac3]

Comment: Thank you Sir! That was very helpful.

Comment: @Suli Don't mention. Glad I helped. If you want you can upvote the answer :-)

Comment: I would. It looks I needed at least 15 reputation to cast a vote and I am new to the site.

Comment: Welcome and good luck with your studies/project, etc :)