How to compute the Jacobian matrix using Mathematica
Apologies if this is posted to the wrong forum. Have been using Maple and Maxima for 20+ years, and have only recently started using Mathematica (v. 14). Having a heck of a time getting Mathematica to do what is trivial in either Maple or Maxima (not a slam on Mathematica - just an honest statement of where I am on the learning curve). Simple example: 2 equations in 2 unknowns (say, x1 and x2). Want to derive the Jacobian of these equations w.r.t. x1 and x2, and print said Jacobian in matrix form. This is basically 3-4 lines in Maple or Maxima. But in Mathematica? Here is what I've tried.
(*Define the functions*)
f1[x1_, x2_] := x1^2 + x2^2
f2[x1_, x2_] := x1 x2

(*Compute the Jacobian matrix with respect to x1 and x2*)
jacobian = JacobianMatrix[{f1[x1, x2], f2[x1, x2]}, {x1, x2}]     

(*Display the Jacobian matrix*) 
MatrixForm[jacobian]

Where I'm stumped is that executing each cell (with shift-enter) causes nothing to be displayed (whereas in Maple, for example, anything you enter is displayed back as soon as you hit the enter key). How do you get Mathematica to do the same thing? Moreoever, if I enter f1 or f2, and hit shift-enter, it doesn't display the equation. Finally, and most frustrating, despite what I've read in the documentation, JacobianMatrix and MatrixForm don't seem to do anything at all (despite what I thought I understood in the documentation).
Many thanks in advance. I was warned the learning curve for Mathematica was appreciably steeper than (say) Maple, but I wasn't expected even something this simple (again, 3-4 lines max in Maple):
f1:=x1^2+x2^2; 
f2:=x1*x2;
jac:=Jacobian([f1,f2],[x1,x2]);

which yields the nicely formatted (2x2) Jacobian matrix. So, in Mathematica?

Looks like JacobianMatrix is a part of a phased out vector analysis package. Does Grad[{f1[x1, x2], f2[x1, x2]}, {x1, x2}] give the answer you're looking for instead? Regarding extracting function definitions back out, try f1[x, y] instead -- in the context provided, the symbol f1 doesn't have any substitutions on it, those are defined on the pattern f1[_, _] instead. In most cases it's a semantic detail, but you may wish to look at DownValues[f1] to see a bit of what's going on under the hood.

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/how-to-make-jacobian-automatically-in-mathematica

In the D documentation, it suggests using the form D[functions, {vars}] for the Jacobian so D[{f1[x1, x2], f2[x1, x2]}, {{x1, x2}}]  in this case

Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3330242

It's a good habit to use immediate assignments (=) whenever possible, and leave the delayed assignments (:=) for the cases where you really need them. Immediate assignments give you immediate feedback, as you would expect from Maple; and this immediate feedback makes it easy to check the progress of a calculation at every step:
f1[x1_, x2_] = x1^2 + x2^2
(*    x1^2 + x2^2    *)

f2[x1_, x2_] = x1 x2
(*    x1 x2    *)

jacobian = D[{f1[x1, x2], f2[x1, x2]}, {{x1, x2}}]
(*    {{2 x1, 2 x2}, {x2, x1}}    *)

MatrixForm[jacobian]

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 x_1 & 2 x_2 \\
 x_2 & x_1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Roman (@ does not work for Roman): See here for other ways by hand.

Funny, @ always works for me. Bad keyboard?

Clear["Global`*"];

f1[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2;
f2[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
f3[x_, y_, z_] = Sin[x y] + z^2 ;

JACOBian[flist_List] := Module[{f, fdefs, vars},
  f = Last@Last@DownValues@# &;
  fdefs = f /@ flist;
  vars = fdefs // Variables // 
     FixedPoint[Map[If[AtomQ[#], #, First@#] &], #] & // Union;
  Outer[D, fdefs, vars]
  ]


JACOBian[{f1, f2}] // MatrixForm

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 x & 2 y \\
 y & x \\
\end{array}
\right)$
JACOBian[{f1, f2, f3}] // MatrixForm

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 x & 2 y & 0 \\
 y & x & 0 \\
 y \cos (x y) & x \cos (x y) & 2 z \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Hard to say if this is correct or not in general. Say I define f1[x_, y_] = x + y and f2[y_, x_] = x (notice the inverted order of arguments), should the correct answer be $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ or $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$? Mathematicians would probably favour the former, and computer scientists the latter (because they'd say that $x$ and $y$ are local variables in the function definitions, not global variables).

Thanks for your comment. I was building up on the comment by @eyorble. I understand that if built-in functionality is not present in Mathematica, then there are good reasons behind it.

This can be done as follows, making use of the command JacobianMatrix.
ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix", 
ResourceSystemBase -> 
"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"][{x1^2 +
 x2^2, x1 x2}, {x1, x2}] // MatrixForm


$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 \text{x1} & 2 \text{x2} \\
 \text{x2} & \text{x1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

